# Creating a multiline regex to find all XML structures in a file containing certain tags and adding attributes

Tags: regex

Dear stackoverflow crowd,

I have a rather difficult RegEx to build, at least difficult to me ;-).

Goal:
Search an XML file (actually XLIFF) for  tags where the attribute approved="yes" is missing and enhancing the  tag with a state="new" attribute. At the same time deleting the text that might be present in the  tag.

Here is an example:

Find this:

```xml
 <trans-unit id="2c5b6ff1">
    <source xml:lang="de-de">Fehler im Aufgabe</source>
    <target xml:lang="en-us">Fehler im Aufgabe</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

and create this output as a replacement:

```xml
 <trans-unit id="2c5b6ff1" approved="no">
    <source xml:lang="de-de">Fehler im Aufgabe</source>
    <target state="new" xml:lang="en-us"></target>
  </trans-unit>
```

I do not want to find structures where the approved value is already set:

```xml
  <trans-unit id="77d29d58-ea84-47b0-a415-1de68425fae0" approved="yes">
    <source xml:lang="de-de">Frequenzumrichter in Störung</source>
    <target xml:lang="en-us" state="translated">Frequency inverter on disturbance</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

I go to this, so far, which is not working properly.

```
(<trans-unit(?!.*?approved=\"yes\".*?\2)[^>]*?)(/?>\r\n        <source xml:lang=\"de-de\">(.*?)<\/source>\r\n<\/trans-unit>)        <target xml:lang=\"en-us\">(.*?)<\/target>\r\n      <\/trans-unit>”
```

What do I need to do differently?

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks a mil!

Comment: Why not using a [XML parser](https://lxml.de/) ?

Comment: Do not parse XLIFF with regex, it is XML. Use BeautifulSoup with lxml parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the super fast suggestions. I guess my phrasing was misleading, I don't want to use a python script, just a regex in python format (not PHP or else). But I will look at the tools and libraries. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

SEARCH for:

```
  (<trans-unit id=\"(.*?)\"(?!.*?approved=\"yes\".*?))>\r\n        <source xml:lang=\"de-de\">(.*?)<\/source>\r\n        <target xml:lang=\"en-us\">(.*?)<\/target>\r\n      <\/trans-unit>
```

REPLACE with:

```
  (<trans-unit id=\"\2" approved=\"no\">\r\n        <source xml:lang=\"de-de\">\3<\/source>\r\n        <target state=\"new\" xml:lang=\"en-us\"><\/target>\r\n      <\/trans-unit>
```

Not very elegant, but it does the job.